# How to prove through induction

Tags: induction

How can I prove by induction that

$$\binom{2n}n<4^n\;?$$

I have solved for the base case, $n=1$, and have formulated the induction hypothesis. I was thinking about Pascal's identity for the rest, but have not been able to come up with a way to use it.

Answer (score 6):

And, of course,
for a non-inductive,
non-original proof:

$\binom{2n}{n}
<\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k}
=(1+1)^{2n}
=2^{2n}
=4^n
$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Pascal’s identity will work. You get

$$\binom{2n+2}{n+1}=\binom{2n+1}{n+1}+\binom{2n+1}n\;.$$

Now notice that $\binom{2n+1}n=\binom{2n+1}{n+1}$, so you can rewrite this as

$$\binom{2n+2}{n+1}=2\binom{2n+1}{n+1}\;.$$

Now apply Pascal’s identity again, and use the fact that the central binomial coefficients are the largest for a given upper number.

Answer (score 3):

**First, show that this is true for $n=1$:**

$\binom{2}{1}<4^{1}$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$\binom{2n}{n}<4^{n}$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$\binom{2n+2}{n+1}=$

$\frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!\cdot(n+1)!}=$

$\frac{(2n)!\cdot(2n+1)\cdot(2n+2)}{(n)!\cdot(n+1)\cdot(n)!\cdot(n+1)}=$

$\frac{(2n)!\cdot(2n+1)\cdot(2n+2)}{(n)!\cdot(n)!\cdot(n+1)\cdot(n+1)}=$

$\frac{(2n)!}{(n)!\cdot(n)!}\cdot\frac{(2n+1)\cdot(2n+2)}{(n+1)\cdot(n+1)}=$

$\color{red}{\binom{2n}{n}}\cdot\frac{(2n+1)\cdot(2n+2)}{(n+1)\cdot(n+1)}\color{red}<$

$\color{red}{4^{n}}\cdot\frac{(2n+\color{blue}{1})\cdot(2n+2)}{(n+1)\cdot(n+1)}\color{blue}<$

$4^{n}\cdot\frac{(2n+\color{blue}{2})\cdot(2n+2)}{(n+1)\cdot(n+1)}=$

$4^{n}\cdot\frac{2(n+1)\cdot2(n+1)}{(n+1)\cdot(n+1)}=$

$4^{n}\cdot2\cdot2=$

$4^{n}\cdot4=$

$4^{n+1}$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

Comment: The third line from the bottom should read $4^n \cdot 2 \cdot 2$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Oooops... Thanks :)