# If I flip $n$ coins, what is the probability of at least $3/4$ of them coming up heads?

Tags: statistics

I'm looking for an equation that will work for any positive integer n. I know that multiple coin flips approaches a normal distribution, but I'm looking for answers that deal specifically with random bits or coin flips. Basically, you can't have 4.2 coins land on heads.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for an exact closed form for the sum $\sum_{k=\lceil 3n/4 \rceil}^{n} {{n}\choose{k}}$.  I don't think there is one.

Answer (score 0):

By definition it is:
$$\begin{align}
\Bbb P \quad 
   & = \quad \sum_{k=\lceil 3n/4\rceil}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}
\\[1ex] & = \quad \tfrac 1{2^n}\sum_{k=\lceil 3n/4\rceil}^n \binom{n}{k} & : p=1/2
\end{align}$$

And that's why Normal approximations get used.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that that would work, but is there any way of doing it without a sigma function?

Comment: You have to use the Normal approximation.

Comment: Is there any way I can answer my original question without a sigma function?

Comment: Also, what would it be using a normal approximation?

Comment: btw, if you want to estimate the probability of getting *exactly* 1/4 heads, the answer is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1208016/show-that-r-kn-n-le-binomknn-r-kn-where-r-k-dfrackkk-1k
It turns out that $\binom{4n}{n} \approx \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3\pi n}}\left(\dfrac{4^4}
{3^3}\right)^{n}$ so that 
$\frac1{2^{4n}}\binom{4n}{n} \approx \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3\pi n}}\left(\dfrac{2^4}
{3^3}\right)^{n}$.

Comment: It's also n!/((n/4)!*(3n/4)!*2^n) That's not what I need either.

Comment: If you use Stirling, you get my approximation.

Comment: Yes, I see why the approximation works, but in this instance, I don't need and can't use an approximation, which brings us back to the point that this is not the problem I need help with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24116/discussion-between-finn-flaherty-and-marty-cohen).

Comment: In other words, $p(n/4) \approx \sqrt{c/n} d^n$ where $c = 8/(3\pi)$ and $d = 2/(3^{3/4}) \approx 0.877$.

Comment: The answer to this question will not be a number, the answer will be a function.