# Lower bound for binomial coefficient

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Prove that for sufficiently large $ n $ the following inequality holds:
$ \binom{5n}{4n}>12^n $. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps expressing the binomial coefficient in terms of factorials and proceeding by induction might help. Either that or you might want to use an identity (perhaps Pascal's or Vandermonde's?).

Comment: I tried induction, i.e. $ \binom{5n+5}{4n+4}=\binom{5n}{4n}\frac{(5n+1)(5n+2)(5n+3)(5n+4)(5n+5)}{(4n+1)(4n+2)(4n+3)(4n+4)} $, but I don't even know if my expansion of binomial coefficient is correct. My main idea was toshow that for some $n$ $ \frac{(5n+1)(5n+2)(5n+3)(5n+4)(5n+5)}{(4n+1)(4n+2)(4n+3)(4n+4)} $ will be greater than $ 12^n $. But I think it's not correct at all.

Comment: @virnoy Your expansion is correct for the induction. However try to figure out why all you need to do is prove that your complicated expression with products/ratios of $(5n + k)$ and $(4n +k)$ is greater than say, 12.5 or 13, not $12^n$ (for large enough $n$). Eventually you will dominate $12^n$ for large enough $n$ if you can prove that.

Comment: So all I need to do is to solve the equation $ \frac{(5n+1)(5n+2)(5n+3)(5n+4)(5n+5)}{(4n+1)(4n‌​+2)(4n+3)(4n+4)}>13 $? I'm right? I don't know if I fully understood you.

Comment: @virnoy It's an inequality, but yes that's all you need to show. And you can replace 13 with any fixed number greater than $12$ that you want, as long as it works for all $n$ large enough.

Comment: @virnoy No problem. And I've left out some of the details, i.e. how to show the inequality $> 12.5$ or $> 13$ or whatever holds, and also why this is enough to show that your original ${{5n} \choose {4n}}$ term will dominate $12^n$ for large enough $n$. But hopefully that won't be too hard.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a_n=\binom{5n}{4n}=\binom{5n}{n}$. We have:

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=5\cdot\frac{(5n+4)\cdot\ldots\cdot(4n+5)}{(5n)\cdot\ldots\cdot(4n+1)}=5\cdot\frac{(5n+4)(5n+3)(5n+2)(5n+1)}{(4n+4)(4n+3)(4n+2)(4n+1)}$$
hence:
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\geq 5\cdot\left(\frac{5n+1}{4n+4}\right)^4 $$
and the RHS is an increasing function with respect to $n$, whose limit when $n\to +\infty$ equals:
$$ 5\cdot\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^4 = 12+\frac{53}{256} $$
hence for any $n$ big enough ($n\geq 23$) we have $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\geq 12+\frac{1}{10}$ and that is enough to prove our claim.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Stirling's approximation, $$\binom{5n}{4n} \sim \sqrt{\frac{5}{4\pi n}} \cdot 5^n \cdot \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^{4n}$$

Now since $5 \cdot \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^4 \approx  12.207 \dots $
$$\frac{\binom{5n}{4n}}{12^n} \sim  \sqrt{\frac{5}{4\pi n}} \cdot \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^{ (0.207 \dots )  n} \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{}\infty$$
and therefore, for $n$ large enough, $\frac{\binom{5n}{4n}}{12^n} >1 $.

Comment: Hi! I think it's the most clear answer. Could you give me the general formula for such approximations?

Answer (score 0):

In an answer to
this question of mine,
[Show that $r_k^n/n \le \binom{kn}{n} < r_k^n$ where $r_k = \dfrac{k^k}{(k-1)^{k-1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1208016/show-that-r-kn-n-le-binomknn-r-kn-where-r-k-dfrackkk-1k),
I showed that

$\binom{kn}{n}
\approx \sqrt{\dfrac{k}{2\pi n(k-1)}}\left(\dfrac{k^k}
{(k-1)^{k-1}}\right)^{n}$

Putting $k=5$,
since
$\frac{5^5}{4^4}
=\frac{3125}{256}
\sim 12.207
$.

$\binom{5n}{4n}
=\binom{5n}{n}
\approx \sqrt{\dfrac{5}{8\pi n}}\left(\dfrac{3125}
{256}\right)^{n}
\approx \sqrt{\dfrac{0.1989}{n}}\left(12.207\right)^{n}
$.