# Proving $\frac1{4ab}\left(\frac{(b+1)^{b+1}}{b^b}\right)^a<\binom{a(b+1)}a<\left(\frac{(b+1)^{b+1}}{b^b}\right)^a$

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients

Let $a\in\mathbb N$, and $b\in\mathbb R, b\geq 1$. How to prove that $$\frac{1}{4ab}\left(\frac{(b+1)^{b+1}}{b^b}\right)^a<\binom{a(b+1)}{a}<\left(\frac{(b+1)^{b+1}}{b^b}\right)^{a}?$$

Comment: Could you tell us what you have tried? Any of your ideas?

Comment: and where this comes from?

Comment: This unsolved problem in my school

Comment: See this question
(with answer)
of mine: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1208016/show-that-r-kn-n-le-binomknn-r-kn-where-r-k-dfrackkk-1k

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes its source, the motivation for the inequality, your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 2):

$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}$**Lemma 1:** If $$f(x) =  \left( 1 + \dfrac{1}{x} \right)^x,\ g(x) =  \left( 1 + \dfrac{1}{x} \right)^{x + 1}, \quad x \geqslant 1$$
then $f$ is strictly increasing but $g$ is strictly decreasing, and$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to +\infty} g(x) = \e.
$$
(This is a well-known result.)

**Lemma 2:** For $m\in \mathbb{N}_+$, $n \in \mathbb{R}$, $n \geqslant 1$,$$
\binom{m + n}{m} < \frac{(m + n)^{m + n}}{m^m n^n}. \tag{2.1}
$$

*Proof of lemma:* (2.1) will be proved by induction on $m$. For $m = 1$,$$
(1) \Longleftrightarrow n + 1 < \frac{(n + 1)^{n + 1}}{n^n} \Longleftrightarrow n^n < (n + 1)^n.
$$
Suppose (2.1) holds for $m$. To prove (2.1) for $m + 1$, it suffices to prove that$$
\left. \binom{m + n + 1}{m + 1} \middle/ \binom{m + n}{m} \right. \leqslant \left. \frac{(m + n + 1)^{m + n + 1}}{(m + 1)^{m + 1} n^n} \middle/ \frac{(m + n)^{m + n}}{m^m n^n} \right.. \tag{2.2}
$$\begin{align*}
(2.2) &\Longleftrightarrow \frac{m + n + 1}{m + 1} \leqslant \frac{m^m (m + n + 1)^{m + n + 1}}{(m + 1)^{m + 1} (m + n)^{m + n}}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \frac{(m + 1)^m}{m^m} \leqslant \frac{(m + n + 1)^{m + n}}{(m + n)^{m + n}}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \left( 1  + \frac{1}{m} \right)^m \leqslant \left( 1 + \frac{1}{m + n} \right)^{m + n}, 
\end{align*}
where the last inequality holds by Lemma 1. End of induction.

**Lemma 3:** For $m\in \mathbb{N}_+$, $n \in \mathbb{R}$, $n \geqslant 1$,$$
\binom{m + n}{m} > \frac{1}{\e m} \frac{(m + n)^{m + n}}{m^m n^n}. \tag{3.1}
$$

*Proof of lemma:* Again, (3.1) will be proved by induction on $m$. For $m = 1$,$$
(3.1) \Longleftrightarrow n + 1 > \frac{1}{\e}·\frac{(n + 1)^{n + 1}}{n^n} \Longleftrightarrow \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n < \e,
$$
where the last inequality is true by Lemma 1.

Suppose (3.1) holds for $m$. To prove (3.1) for $m + 1$, it suffices to prove that$$
\left. \binom{m + n + 1}{m + 1} \middle/ \binom{m + n}{m} \right. \geqslant \left. \frac{(m + n + 1)^{m + n + 1}}{(m + 1)^{m + 2} n^n} \middle/ \frac{(m + n)^{m + n}}{m^{m + 1} n^n} \right.. \tag{3.2}
$$\begin{align*}
(3.2) &\Longleftrightarrow \frac{m + n + 1}{m + 1} \geqslant \frac{m^{m + 1} (m + n + 1)^{m + n + 1}}{(m + 1)^{m + 2} (m + n)^{m + n}}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \frac{(m + 1)^{m + 1}}{m^{m + 1}} \geqslant \frac{(m + n + 1)^{m + n}}{(m + n)^{m + n}}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \left( 1  + \frac{1}{m} \right)^{m + 1} \geqslant \left( 1 + \frac{1}{m + n} \right)^{m + n},
\end{align*}
where the last inequality holds because by Lemma 1,$$
\left( 1  + \frac{1}{m} \right)^{m + 1} \geqslant \e \geqslant \left( 1 + \frac{1}{m + n} \right)^{m + n}.
$$
End of induction.

---

Now for $a \in \mathbb{N}_+$, $b \geqslant 1$, take $(m, n) = (a, ab)$ in Lemma 2, then$$
\binom{a(b + 1)}{a} < \frac{(ab + a)^{ab + a}}{a^a (ab)^{ab}} = \frac{a^{ab + a} (b + 1)^{ab + a}}{a^{ab + a} b^{ab}} = \left( \frac{(b + 1)^{b + 1}}{b^b} \right)^a.
$$

Take $(m, n) = (a, ab)$ in Lemma 3, then$$
\binom{a(b + 1)}{a} > \frac{1}{\e a} \frac{(ab + a)^{ab + a}}{a^a (ab)^{ab}} = \frac{1}{\e a} \left( \frac{(b + 1)^{b + 1}}{b^b} \right)^a \geqslant \frac{1}{4ab} \left( \frac{(b + 1)^{b + 1}}{b^b} \right)^a.
$$

Answer (score 1):

In this question of mine
([Show that $r_k^n/n \le \binom{kn}{n} < r_k^n$ where $r_k = \dfrac{k^k}{(k-1)^{k-1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1208016/show-that-r-kn-n-le-binomknn-r-kn-where-r-k-dfrackkk-1k))
I show both that
for $n \ge 2$, 
$\dfrac{r_k^n}{n+1} \le \binom{kn}{n} < r_k^n$ where $r_k = \frac{k^k}{(k-1)^{k-1}}$
and
$\binom{kn}{n}
\approx \sqrt{\dfrac{k}{2\pi n(k-1)}}\left(\dfrac{k^k}
{(k-1)^{k-1}}\right)^{n}
$.