# complexity of $\ {n \choose n/3}$

Tags: computational-complexity

I know  that the complexity of this combination $\ {n \choose n/3}$ is of $\theta(n^{n/3})$ , but I'm in need of help proving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that
by "complexity"
you mean the value.

In

[Show that $r_k^n/n \le \binom{kn}{n} < r_k^n$ where $r_k = \dfrac{k^k}{(k-1)^{k-1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1208016/show-that-r-kn-n-le-binomknn-r-kn-where-r-k-dfrackkk-1k)

I showed that
for $n \ge 2$, 
$$\dfrac{r_k^n}{n+1} \le \binom{kn}{n} < r_k^n 
\text{ where }
r_k = \frac{k^k}{(k-1)^{k-1}}
$$
and,
if you use Stirling's formula,
you get
$$\binom{kn}{n}
\approx \sqrt{\dfrac{k}{2\pi n(k-1)}}r_k^{n}
$$

Putting $k=3$ 
and
$n = n/3$,
this becomes
for $n \ge 2$,

$\dfrac{r_3^{n/3}}{n/3+1} 
\le \binom{n}{n/3} 
< r_3^{n/3}$ 
where 
$r_3 
= \frac{3^3}{2^2}
= \frac{27}{4}
$

and
$\binom{n}{n/3}
\approx \sqrt{\dfrac{9}{4\pi n}}r_3^{n/3}
$.

Comment: Do you mean $\sim$ instead of $\approx$ ?

Comment: The ratio goes to $1$. So use whichever you want.